# Are there any pain scales which measure how much of the body is in pain?

Tags: pain

Are there any [pain scales](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pain_scale) which talk about the extent of pain, i.e. how much of the body is in pain?

I'm in the process of trying to work out whether several lesions, hurt with the same *intensity* as a single lesion of the same severity.